# Error argument of AND must be type boolean not type integer

Tags: postgresql

I want to update a column, in the where statement I did a subselect and it gave me an error and said:
Error argument of AND must be type boolean not type integer

```
UPDATE setelt
SET active = 'N' 
FROM rule
WHERE setelt.active = 'Y' AND
    (SELECT ac.approval_configurationno_i
    FROM ac
    LEFT JOIN rule
    ON ac.ruleno_i = rule.xmlruleno_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query's where condition is not true. You must use Subquery expression. Please check [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html) article. You can find which one do you need.

I don't know your tables but your sql should be like that;

```
WHERE setelt.active = 'Y' AND 1 = ALL(SELECT ac.approval_configurationno_i
FROM ac
LEFT JOIN rule
ON ac.ruleno_i = rule.xmlruleno_i)
```